# 'Qt:AlignmentFlag' [-fpermissive]

Tags: qt

I'm new in Qt.

When I compile below code, I get error *"invalid conversion from 'int' Qt::Alignment Flag' -fpermissive in Qt"* in **/1/**, **/2/**, **/3/**, **/4/** and /**5/** lines.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow() {
    createGridGroupBox();

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    mainLayout -> addWidget(gridGroupBox);

    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Layout Örneği"));

    resize(600,600);
}

void MainWindow::createGridGroupBox() {
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    gridGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Grid Layout"));

    label1 = new QLabel(tr("Kaynak Resmin Yolu: ").arg(1));
    layout -> addWidget(label1, 0, 0);

    lineEdit1 = new QLineEdit;
/*1*/   layout -> addWidget(lineEdit1, 0, 1);

    label2 = new QLabel(tr("Kaynak Resmin Görseli: ").arg(2));
    layout -> addWidget(label2, 1, 0);

    /*label3 = new QLabel(tr("Şablon Resmin Yolu: ").arg(3));
    layout -> addWidget(label3, 2, 0);*/

    label4 = new QLabel(tr("Şablon Resmin Yolu: ").arg(4));
    layout -> addWidget(label4, 3, 0);

    lineEdit2 = new QLineEdit;
/*2*/    layout -> addWidget(lineEdit2, 3, 1);

    label5 = new QLabel(tr("Şablon Resmin Görseli: ").arg(5));
    layout -> addWidget(label5, 4, 0);

    /*label6 = new QLabel(tr("Kaynak Resmin Yolu: ").arg(6));
    layout -> addWidget(label6, 5, 0);*/

    label7 = new QLabel(tr("Şablon Eşleştirme İşleminin Sonucunun Görseli: ").arg(7));
/*3*/    layout -> addWidget(label7, 0, 2);

    /*label8 = new QLabel(tr("Şablon Eşleştirme İşleminin Sonucunun Görseli: ").arg(8));
    layout -> addWidget(label8, 1, 2, 4, 1);*/

/*4*/    label9 = new QLabel(tr("Sonuç: ").arg(9));
    layout -> addWidget(label9, 2, 2);

    lineEdit3 = new QLineEdit;
/*5*/    layout -> addWidget(lineEdit3, 2, 3);

    gridGroupBox -> setLayout(layout);
}
```

Comment: Out of interest's sake, what are you trying to accomplish with all the `.arg()` statements? I ask because you're not using any of them correctly and they're essentially doing nothing.

Comment: I reviewed one website and  example in in this website contained .arg(). So I used .arg(). Frankly, I don't know .arg().

Comment: If that's the case, remove all your `arg()` statements, they're not accomplishing anything. If you'd like to know what they are used for, look in the class reference for `QString`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I use Qt since one weeks. I'm very beginner in Qt. So advices is very important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is to be expected.

The `addWidget()` function for the `QHBoxLayout` class is defined as:

```
void addWidget(QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)
```

Perhaps you were meaning to use a `QGridLayout`?

Comment: I will research about Qt::Alignment.

Comment: By the way you were using the `addWidget()` function, it looks like you were trying to add a widget to a layout by specifying the row and column of where that widget should be. The `QHBoxLayout` only displays widgets in a horizontal row, not in a grid. If you want your widgets to be in a grid layout, you have to use `QGridLayout` instead.

Comment: This answer is perfect :) I replace QHBoxLayout with QGridLayout and my problem solved. Thanks a lot RobbieE :)